# If I add a div between two select, Javascript does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use two Select. If you choose the first select, the other becomes active. But when I use the div tag, JavaScript stops working.

This is **working** version [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emresaracoglu/3dpntdzu/)

This is **not working** version without DIV tags [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emresaracoglu/6096w00a/1/)

*This is **working** version on StackOverFlow*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this).find(':selected');
    var rel = $this.data('rel');
    $(this).next('select').show()
      .find('option').hide()
      .end().find('option[data-rel="' + rel + '"]').show()
      .first().prop('selected', true);
    $(this).next('select').next('select').hide()
  });
});
```

```css
.cate {
  display: none;
}

.cate2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">


  <select name="bcNewAd_mainCat" class="chosen-select-no-single">
    <option value="0" data-rel="">Choose</option>
    <option value="1" data-rel="accessories">Cellphones</option>
    <option value="2" data-rel="sports">Sports</option>
    <option value="2" data-rel="cars">Cars</option>
  </select>
  <select name="bcNewAd_subCat" class="chosen-select-no-single cate">
    <option value="0" data-rel="">Choose</option>
    <option value="3" data-rel="accessories">Smartphone</option>
    <option value="8" data-rel="accessories">Charger</option>
    <option value="1" data-rel="sports">Basketball</option>
    <option value="4" data-rel="cars">Tesla</option>

  </select>
</div>
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Try use  `$('.cate').show()` instead `$(this).next('select').show()`

Comment: @לבנימלכה Working thank you. If you're the answer writer, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: happy to help!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.next()
```

> **Description**: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in
>   the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves
>   the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

when you add `div`  they not sibling any more 

 **SO try this:**

```
$('.cate').show()
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('select').change(function() {
     var $this = $(this).find(':selected');
     var rel = $this.data('rel');
     $('.cate').show()
       .find('option').hide()
       .end().find('option[data-rel="' + rel + '"]').show()
       .first().prop('selected', true);
     $(this).next('select').next('select').hide()
   });
 });
```

```css
.cate {
  display: none;
}

.cate2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">


  <select name="bcNewAd_mainCat" class="chosen-select-no-single">
    <option value="0" data-rel="">Choose</option>
    <option value="1" data-rel="accessories">Cellphones</option>
    <option value="2" data-rel="sports">Sports</option>
    <option value="2" data-rel="cars">Cars</option>
</select> </div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <select name="bcNewAd_subCat" class="chosen-select-no-single cate">
    <option value="0" data-rel="">Choose</option>
    <option value="3" data-rel="accessories">Smartphone</option>
    <option value="8" data-rel="accessories">Charger</option>
    <option value="1" data-rel="sports">Basketball</option>
    <option value="4" data-rel="cars">Tesla</option>
    
</select></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because .next() selects the next SIBLING, when you add the div, you separate the children.

Comment: Thank you also nice analogy :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$(this).next('select').show()`, this selects the next sibling select element from DOM and displays it, which doesn't exist now as the select is now in a div.

Use id selector, to bind events on specific select, if you want to keep the div.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#firstSelect').change(function() {
     var $this = $(this).find(':selected');
     var rel = $this.data('rel');
        $("#secondSelect").show()
       .find('option').hide()
       .end().find('option[data-rel="' + rel + '"]').show()
       .first().prop('selected', true);
     //$(this).next('select').next('select').hide()
   });
 });
```

```css
.cate {
  display: none;
}

.cate2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">


  <select id="firstSelect" name="bcNewAd_mainCat" class="chosen-select-no-single">
<option value="0" data-rel="">Choose</option>
<option value="1" data-rel="accessories">Cellphones</option>
<option value="2" data-rel="sports">Sports</option>
<option value="2" data-rel="cars">Cars</option>
</select> </div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <select id="secondSelect" name="bcNewAd_subCat" class="chosen-select-no-single cate">
<option value="0" data-rel="">Choose</option>
<option value="3" data-rel="accessories">Smartphone</option>
<option value="8" data-rel="accessories">Charger</option>
<option value="1" data-rel="sports">Basketball</option>
<option value="4" data-rel="cars">Tesla</option>

</select></div>
```